# Formate date in timeseries chart

Tags: looker-studio

I want to know how to format the date in the Time series chart in Data (Looker) Studio.

I want the date to look like "%d/%m/%Y, %A" (example: 01/04/2023, Saturday).

Until now, I could not find the function that would change the format and work with Time Series.

I tried TODATE(date,"%Y/%m/%d", "%d/%m/%Y, %A"), but that did not work on the Time series (the date is transformed into a string). However, it worked for Line Chart.

I want the capabilities of time series char. So is there a solution to this?